# Debian cannot reboot nor shutdown

Tags: linux, debian, shutdown, reboot, systemd

I'm stuck with a simple problem of rebooting with my installation of `Debian 7`.

I got inspired by [this issue](http://linux.koolsolutions.com/2009/08/04/howto-fix-linux-hangfreeze-during-reboots-and-restarts/) but it's not working. I tried a lot of combinations but still nothing.

I'm not sure about the diagnosis. When I try `reboot` or `shutdown` there is still the same thing: the machine seems to shut down or reboot but it never stops.

I'm using a `Gigabytes Brix BXCE 2955` with `Gnome 3.4.2`.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of these commands to reboot or shut down your machine:

```
reboot -f

halt

poweroff
```

If the machine doesn't reboot and hanged still, then you can use combination of keys from your keyboard which will avoid data corruption by forcibly shutting down your machine.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>

Each letter is meant for a specific task,

unRaw      (take control of keyboard back from X),
 tErminate (send SIGTERM to all processes, allowing them to terminate gracefully),
 kIll      (send SIGKILL to all processes, forcing them to terminate immediately),
  Sync     (flush data to disk),
  Unmount  (remount all filesystems read-only),
reBoot.

Comment: `reboot -f` is working but my restart button isn't. When it's not working (form button action) I tried what you said `ALT + PrintScreen + R E I S U B` but nothing happened. Isn't it possible to change action made by the button to force the command `reboot -f`? By the way, `shutdown -hF now` doesn't work.

Comment: A little late but isn't it `ctrl + alt + PrintScreen + R E I S U B` ?